# Parent/child permissions grouping

Tags: permissions, hierarchy, aspnetboilerplate

According to the documentation on [Authorization](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Authorization), I can use child permissions to group all related permissions to their parents:

> "Permissions can have parent and child permissions. While this does not affect permission checking, it helps to group the permissions in the UI."

As an example, I would like to create a parent `Permission` "User Management"
with "Create" , "Read", "Update" and "Delete" sub-permissions.

However, after setting my permission in `SetPermissions`, the hierarchy is not persisted anywhere so there's no way for me to know how permissions are related to each other from UI's perspective because the JSON returned is all flattened and the `AbpPermissions` table doesn't look like it maintains this either.

Here's my code snippet (Fig. 1)

[image: Fig1]

And here's my `AbpPermissions` table (Fig. 2)

[image: Fig2]

I would appreciate any suggestion or any insight on this.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`Permission`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/44b5b87eff2f84f539b93426a997b09af45eb711/src/Abp/Authorization/Permission.cs) is already hierachical, with `Parent` and `Children` properties.

You can retrieve the structure that you defined using:

```cs
var rootPermissions = _permissionManager.GetAllPermissions()
    .Where(p => p.Parent == null)
    .ToList();
```

You can then recursively iterate the `rootPermissions` and check if it is granted:

```cs
var isAssigned = _permissionChecker.IsGranted(permission.Name);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Interesting! Indeed the code snippet you provided shows the proper hierarchy when debugging, If I may enquire more though, how does GetAllPermissions establishes the hierarchy? I don't see any referential relation in the DB. 
Also how come it's not reflected in the json of role permission in the startup template? 
"permissions":["Pages.Roles","Pages.Contractors","Pages.Contracts","Pages.Setup","Pages.DocumentManagement","Pages.Documents","Pages.ContractManagement","Pages.Events","Users","Users.Create","Users.Edit"]
Thank you very much!

Comment: The hierarchy that you define in your `AuthorizationProvider` is persisted in memory — more specifically, in the [`Permissions`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/44b5b87eff2f84f539b93426a997b09af45eb711/src/Abp/Authorization/PermissionDefinitionContextBase.cs#L10) property in the base class of `PermissionManager`.